# Omniture Saint.ImportCreateJob

Tags: adobe-analytics

This is a very specific Omniture API question. Thought I'd check here if anyone encountered this problem since Omniture forum was not of much help -

Sending the following parameters to Omniture API Explorer here - https://developer.omniture.com/en_US/get-started/api-explorer#Saint.ImportCreateJob seems to work fine.

```
{
"check_divisions":"1",
"description":"OSRA job description: MyReportID, Products, 51",
"email_address":"my@email.com",
"export_results":"0",
"header":["Field1", "Field2"],
"overwrite_conflicts":"1",
"relation_id":51,
"report_suite_array":["MyReportID"],
"c_view":"SomeReportName"
}
```

But the call fails in the actual code with a 'Bad Request'. It seems like `c_view` parameter is expecting a certain value. The only documentation for `c_view` is that it expects a report name. I've tried report names and other values with no luck. Would appreciate any pointers from Omniture API users.

Thanks.

Comment: try using the relevant value from here: https://developer.omniture.com/en_US/documentation/omniture-administration/r-classification-view#reference_6C295C6101D14F29B70F21B19BEB0868  I know this is what you need for using the get/save classifications methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

c_value is not required, so unless you plan on using it, it does not need to be present. It is supposed to be a classification_view https://developer.omniture.com/en_US/documentation/omniture-administration/r-classification-view.

It takes some trial and error to get this api working.
Here is an example of a call I use that works using the REST api over Java:

Request:

```
{
"check_divisions":1,
"description":"Report Test 1",
"email_address":"cdegroot@adobe.com",
"export_results":"0",
"overwrite_conflicts":0,
"relation_id":65,
"report_suite_array":["cdgdev"],
"header":["Key","Survey","Survey^Question","Survey^Question^Response","Engagement Index","Survey > Question > Response"]
}
```

Response:

```
"3387166"
```

Kind Regards C.

Answer (score 1):

try using the relevant value from the [classification_view](https://developer.omniture.com/en_US/documentation/omniture-administration/r-classification-view#reference_6C295C6101D14F29B70F21B19BEB0868) chart. I know this is what you need for using the get/save classifications methods (I have used those methods, but not the `Saint.ImportCreateJob` method).